# Why is there no $\pi$ in an ellipse?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

Allow me to clarify ...

With a circle of circumference $c$ and diameter $d$, $\pi$ makes an appearance as $\frac{c}{d}$ even though the equation of a circle, $(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$, *doesn't* contain $\pi$.

I know that for an *ellipse* there *is* a constant, $C = 2a$ where the combined distance of a point $P$ on the ellipse from the two foci = twice the major radius. I was wonder though whether there's anything $\pi$-ish about an ellipse's *circumference* and "diameter"? Is it possible that if $R$ is the *mean* of the major and minor radii of an ellipse and $C$ the ellipse's circumference, $\frac{C}{2R} \approx \pi$?

*Do nfr things*

Comment: The area of an ellipse with major radius $a$ and minor radius $b$ is $\pi ab$. The ellipse is a circle precisely when $a=b$. The perimeter has no easy exact formula, but it can be approximated and many approximation formulas involve $\pi$, $a$, and $b$, among other quantities.

Comment: I'm amazed there's no "ellipses" tag.  Could someone create or suggest it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a $\pi$ in both the area and perimeter formulas.

[image]

Comment: Don't use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [Here is why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). Also no attribution, so potential misuse, plagiarism, or violation of copyright laws. Well done. -1.

Comment: The post was helpful, but you're right.

Comment: Arturo - This is a Q&A site, not a college paper, and I'm not making money here.  Educational use is fair use.  Chill out, dude.  (For the record, it's my own book that I'm writing.)

Comment: Before making pronouncements about fair use, you should consult an attorney, as by posting here you grant use license to *your* work, but you cannot do that to work of others. Plagiarism is an issue that is not constrained to "college papers", so your comment about them is both irrelevant and dumb. And posting huge swats of text as pictures is still highly problematic, as explained in the link I pointed you too. but which you clearly think you are too "chill" to bother with.